# Bullfighting is banned in Barcelona?

Tags: production, film-location, the-gunman

In the movie credits to Sean Penn's *The Gunman* (2015), it reads "Barcelona is an anti-bullfighting city and no bullfighting has taken place in the city since 2011".

In the movie the climactic scene occurs in a bullfighting arena, although it is not clear that it is in Barcelona.

Why is this disclaimer present? The bullfighting scene was shot in Barcelona, an "anti-bullfighting" city? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4):

Much like Jeeped said in the comments, Catalonia and its capital Barcelona have banned bullfighting since the early 2010's. The bullfighting arenas are still present, and are used for other events.

The city council probably wouldn't want an international movie depicting Barcelona as a place where bullfighting takes place, since it is a controversial activity to say the least. So in order to allow the scene, it is likely they requested the disclaimer.

Comment: The truth is it is not. They've banned the traditional spanish bullfighting. The traditional Catalan way of torturing bulls by burning them with gunpowder and pinch them with knifes and arrows is allowed all over Catalonia and very rooted indeed

Answer (score 0):

The movie takes place in 2006, and bullfighting has been banned since 2010. So while showing a bullfight is an accurate depiction of Barcelona within the film's setting, it is not an accurate depiction of current Barcelona.

Comment: Bullfighting was banned in the Spanish autonomous community of Catalonia by a vote of the Catalan Parliament in July 2010. The ban came into effect on January 1, 2012. The last bullfight in the region took place in Barcelona in September 2011. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_on_bullfighting_in_Catalonia))

Comment: Could the person who downvoted explain why?

Comment: You've blatantly misstated facts. I've supplied the correct information if you care to [edit] it in. BTW, the bullfight was filmed in Madrid; it was only represented as Barcelona. Drop me another @Jeeped comment if you change the narrative and I'll reconsider my position.

Comment: @Jeeped What facts have I misstated?

Comment: The mis-stated fact is the ban has been in place since 2012 not 2010.